# Flexbox alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align the Modern Art Gallery and the text using flexbox but when I do that the whole container moves left and right. Even more so I want to change the width of the h1 but I'm not sure how to do that.

Some code may be missing as I'm working on multiple devices but I only need help with the desktop version which is what's shown.

Here's what I want it to look like:
[image]

```css
.container-content {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.container-content h1 {
  font-size: 96px;
  padding: 0;
}

#tablet-img {
  display: none;
}

#desktop-img {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  padding-left: 450px;
}

.desktop-text-button {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 1%;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="container-flex">
  <img id="desktop-img" src="../art-gallery-website/starter-code/assets/desktop/image-hero.jpg" alt="desktop-image">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="container-content">

      <h1>MODERN ART GALLERY</h1>

      <div class="desktop-text-button">
        <p>The arts in the collection of the Modern Art Gallery all started from a spark of inspiration. Will these pieces inspire you? Visit us and find out.</p>

        <div class="button-1">
          <button>Our Location</button>
          <span class="right-arrow"></span>

        </div>

      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was messy so I just recoded it. Is this what you want?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
}

.wrapper .left {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/4707236.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1.2px solid #000000;
}

.wrapper .left p {
  font-size: 6vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.wrapper .left p span {
  color: #000000;
}

.wrapper .right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  column-gap: 2vh;
  position: relative;
  right: 7%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.wrapper .right p {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.wrapper .right button {
  font-size: 1.6vw;
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <p>MODERN <br /> ART GAL<span>LERY</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>The arts in the collection of the Modern Art Gallery all started from a spark of inspiration. Will these pieces inspire you? Visit us and find out.</p>
    <button>OUR LOCATION</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it was! I wasn't expecting the color aspect, just the flexbox but I appreciate your input!